# Long box around some objects in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

[image: knots, braids and the bracket polynomial]

How do I make the sloped red lines of the box match the slope of the tikz-cd arrow? Other than changing the coordinates by visual inspection, is there some way so that the bounding red lines exactly match the slope of the arrow? I also get a warning of `Overfull \hbox (12.18117pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--16`. I want to center the figure so that it is in the center of the slide as well. Adding `xshift` to center manually by visual inspection seems to garble the figure. It would be nice to have the text vertically centered in the box as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
                \draw[thick, red] (-1.15,-2.8) -- (-2.3,-0.65) -- (-5.6,-0.65) -- (-5.6,1.1) -- (-1.9,1.1) -- (0,-0.9) -- (5.6,-0.9) -- (5.6,-2.8) -- cycle;
            }]
            & & {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Jones} \\ \text{algebra}\end{array}} \arrow{r}{\text{\normalsize Markov}}[swap]{\text{\normalsize trace}} &[5em] {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Jones} \\ \text{polynomial}\end{array}} \\
            {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Oriented}\\ \text{link}\end{array}} \arrow[r] & {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Artin} \\ \text{braid} \\ \text{group}\end{array}} \arrow[rd, sloped, "\text{Repres.}"] \arrow[ru, sloped, "\text{Repres.}"] & & \\
            & & {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Temperley--} \\ \text{Lieb} \\ \text{algebra}\end{array}} \arrow{r}{\text{\normalsize Diagrammatic}}[swap]{\text{\normalsize trace}} &[5em] {\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\text{Normalised}\\ \text{bracket}\\ \text{polynomial}\end{array}} \arrow[uu, leftrightarrow, sloped, above, "\text{\normalsize Substitution}"]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask why you're drawing tjis in tikz-CD and not in tikz directly, then no need for those arrays and you can either draw the box via the nodrs

Comment: @daleif I am not that familiar with tikz. But yes, I should have used tikz directly. I shall read the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your background is blank anyway, you could just use the `double` option with a very big `double distance`. Here I'm just guessing `5em`, though it would be possible to have TikZ measure all nodes and figure it out more automatic.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, backgrounds}
\newcommand*\tmnl[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzcd}[
  math mode=false, labels={align=center},
  execute at end picture={
    \scoped[on background layer]
      \draw[red, thick, name prefix=\tikzcdmatrixname-,
            double distance=5em, line cap=rect]
        plot coordinates {(2-1)(2-2)(3-3)(3-4)};}]
&
&      \tmnl{Jones \\ algebra}        \arrow[r, "Markov\\trace" auto=false]
&[5em] \tmnl{Jones \\ polynomial} \\
       \tmnl{Oriented \\ link}        \arrow[r]
&      \tmnl{Artin \\ braid \\ group} \arrow[rd, sloped, "Repres."]
                                      \arrow[ru, sloped, "Repres."] \\
&
& \tmnl{Temperley-- \\ Lieb \\ algebra}
                        \arrow[r, "Diagrammatic\\swap"' auto=false]
& \tmnl{Normalised \\ bracket \\ polynomial}
                 \arrow[uu, leftrightarrow, sloped, "Substitution"]
\end{tikzcd}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]